# What is the difference between creating a temp table in SQL Server as #TempTable and TempDb.dbo.TembName and which one gives better performance?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temp-tables

What is the main difference between #TempTable and TempDb.dbo.TembName. Because they are both temp tables at the end of the day. So why should I use one over the other?

Comment: #TempTable is also created in TempDB and persisted until it is dropped.

Answer (score 2):

There is no performance difference.  A #TempTable is only visible to a single session and is automatically dropped at the end of the session (if created in a top-level batch), or the end of the batch or stored procedure (if created in a nested batch or stored procedure).  A regular table in tempdb is visible to all sessions and won't be automatically dropped until the server restarts.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing difference in performance but the #temp table are emptied at the end of the user session (in many situations the schema remains in the cache from SQL Server 2005) while a normal table remains in TempDB until you will restart the istance or drop it manually.

There are many differences instead between **temp tables** and **table variables**.
Both are in TempDB (to dispel some myths) but:

- By default temp tables have the statistics while for tables variables the engine always estimates 1 row (also with InMemory option).
  From CU3 di SQL 2014 and SP2 di SQL 2012 you can enable the statistics in table variables with trace flag 2453 but you have to be careful of the impacts in terms of performances.
- Before SQL Server 2014 if you need to add nonclustered index, in tables variables you can’t add it inline and take advantage of [objects caching](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/SQL-Workshops/Temp-Table-Caching-in-SQL-Server) introduced with SQL Server 2005.
- The temp tables support the transactions while the table variables does not support it.
- Temp tables are accessible from stored procedures called inside the one that created them while tables variable no.
- Table variables doesn’t support the [TRUNCATE TABLE](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/statements/truncate-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) statement while temp tables support it.
- Basically the tables variable require much less latch and transaction log records than temp tables.